# Valor default do TextField Select no Material-ui

Tags: react, material-ui

É uma dúvida básica, estou tentando deixar o valor default como vazio, mas ele acaba sempre preenchendo com o primeiro item:

```
<TextField
        select
        id="letter"
        name="letter"
        label="Letra"
        defaultValue=""
        SelectProps={{
          native: true
        }}
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        fullWidth
      >
        <option key={1} value={1}>
          A
        </option>
        <option key={3} value={2}>
          B
        </option>
        <option key={3} value={3}>
          C
        </option>
</TextField>
```

Segue o codesandbox com o exemplo citado
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-select-2jw0c?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se é a melhor forma, mas adicionei isso e funcionou aqui:

`<option disabled selected value={""}></option>`